# babel-plugin-root-import with babel 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm trying to setup Babel 7. Never used Babel before, so i'm really starting from scratch. I've managed to install and use `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`, but I'm struggling with `babel-plugin-root-import`.

Here is my package.json

```
//package.json

"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
  "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
  "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.1.0"
}


//babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],
    ["babel-plugin-root-import",{
      "rootPathPrefix": "@"
    }]
  ]
};
```

Below is my code:

```
//src/index.js

require("./foo/index.js")();

//src/foo/index.js

module.exports = function() {
  console.log("Foo loaded")
}
```

When I execute the code above, I get `Foo loaded` in my console.

When I change src/index.js with the following:

```
//src/index.js

require("@/foo/index.js")();
```

I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../foo/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Node.js\dev\babel7\src/index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\Node.js\dev\babel7\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:91:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Node.js\dev\babel7\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:96:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

If I don't set the rootPathPrefix in babel.config.js, I also cannot use the plugin with paths starting with ~, which is supposed to be the default value.
What is wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: I believe in the "When I change" section you meant `require("@/foo/index.js")();`. That is my assumption in the answer below.

Comment: You are correct, this was a typo:) I've corrected the question.

Comment: Take a look at [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#getting-started), with the configuration options it provides you could e.g. set `root` as `.` and alias `@` as `./src`, and you end up without needing to type `@/src`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will have a look at this plugin, although I achieved exactly what I needed with the help of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run babel-cli directly with `npx babel src/index.js` just to check the output, you will find that the root import plugin is correctly changing:

```
require("@/foo/index.js")();
```

into:

```
require("../foo/index.js")();
```

`@` (the project root) is correctly replaced in the `index.js` file *inside the src folder* with `..`

If you want `@` to refer to `root/src` you can set the `"rootPathSuffix": "src"` option. Without that option you would have to do:

```
require("@/src/foo/index.js")();
```

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the suffix chapter in the doc. It works now. Thanks for your help!